# compiling lua, getting makefile CreateProcess error

Tags: windows, lua, makefile

I'm trying to compile Lua 1.1. Why? Because I can. Here's the makefile contents.

```
all:
    (cd src; make)
    (cd clients/lib; make)
    (cd clients/lua; make)

clean:
    (cd src; make clean)
    (cd clients/lib; make clean)
    (cd clients/lua; make clean)
```

Here's the error I get just from running `make all`.

```
(cd src; make)
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), (cd src; make), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why do I get this error? I'm on WinXP-32.

Comment: The 1994 Lua 1.1? that's like vintage :)

Comment: It's a great language and I come to find out 5.1 is like ~60 files so I went all the way down to 1.1 and there's only 6 or so. I want to learn about interpreters/compilers/languages/etc. so this is a pretty good start for me.

Comment: You may also be interested in this: http://www.reddit.com/comments/63hth/ask_reddit_which_oss_codebases_out_there_are_so/c02pxbp

Comment: Thanks. I was going to work my way up to see how the language evolved (well, not reading all versions, probably 1.1, 5.1, and something in between) so this will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I can.

Your post begs to differ. :)

That makefile is written for Linux (which uses ';' as a command separator). The Windows command interpreter will choke on that.

You're going to need to edit those makefiles, or try the following command line (I'm using Visual Studio's command line compiler, substitute your compiler if necessary):

```
cl clients\lua\*.c clients\lib\*.c src\*.c -I include
```

Comment: Okay, it gives me more errors :(. `<.c src file> fatal error C1083 mm.h no file or directory`. It does this for mm.h and lua.h for for about 7 different .c files. Can I just edit the makefiles for windows then? That's easy right?

Comment: You need to do it from the root of the distribution directory.

Comment: Oh, I added files from /include to /src and it I got through. I think I was doing it from the root. Okay, the files (.obj I guess?) are in the same place where the vs command prompt is.

Comment: If `lua.c` was included, it has a `main` defined, so you should now have a `lua.exe`.

Comment: iolib is not compiling, it has an error. `iolib.c(29): C2099: initializer not a constant` for `static FILE *in=stdin, *out=stdout;`. I just did a google search and it looks like I need to set them to 0, but init them in function IIRC, so probably to main() brb

Comment: Alright looks like Lua is awesome and it reroutes the in and out vars if the are NULL, sweet. It named the .exe `hash.exe` lol. It works.  I typed `print("hi")` and it worked. Thank you for all your help :).

Answer (score 3):

Get [lua-all.tar.gz](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-all.tar.gz) which contains the source of all Lua distributions with a few changes made to make them easy to compile.